# Create singleton class with Android context as param in constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android I app I need to create singleton class and pass android context as param to constructor:

snippet:

```
class RecognizedCheckDataService private constructor(context: Context) {
    private var context: Context? = null

    init { // default constructor
        this.context = context
        recognizedCheckDataDir =
            AndroidFileUtil.getInternalStoragePath(context, RECOGNIZED_CHECK_DATA)
    }

    companion object {
        var recognizedCheckDataDir: File? = null
        private val RECOGNIZED_CHECK_DATA = "RECOGNIZED_CHECK_DATA"
        private var instance: RecognizedCheckDataService? = null

        private val TAG = RecognizedCheckDataService::class.java.name

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): RecognizedCheckDataService {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = RecognizedCheckDataService(context)
            }
            return instance as RecognizedCheckDataService
        }

        fun deleteRecognizedCheckDataDir(): Boolean {
            try {
                // first check is exist and then delete
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(recognizedCheckDataDir);
                return true
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use:

```
class Main : Application() {
    companion object {
        private lateinit var appContext: Context

        fun getAppContext(): Context {
            return appContext
        }    

    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        //Debug.d(TAG, "onCreate: ENTRY_POINT")
        init()
    }

 private fun init() {
        appContext = this
        RecognizedCheckDataService.getInstance(appContext)
    }
}
```

Is this a correct way?

Comment: Storing `Context` in Singleton class can lead to an issue.

Comment: Be sure to call `applicationContext` on whatever `Context` is supplied to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Why not pass the `PATH` as an argument rather than using context? you don't really need the context in there :/

Comment: @RodrigoQueiroz I need context to get internal path like this; AndroidFileUtil.getInternalStoragePath(context)  -> context.getDir(folderName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

Comment: I know, what I meant is that you can get the path from within the Android application context being from an Activity/Fragment and then calling your singleton with that path.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this can help you.

```kotlin
class Singleton {
    var mContext: Context

    constructor(context: Context) {
        mContext = context
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: HttpClientService? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): HttpClientService {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = HttpClientService(context)
            }

            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. I don't think you need ```var mContext: Context

    constructor(context: Context) {
        mContext = context
    }``` Android Studio shows a warning that this could lead to a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer this method whenever i want to use singleton object in my project

you often need to pass a Context instance to initialization blocks of singleton components so they can retrieve file paths, read settings or access services, but you also want to avoid keeping a static reference to it (even if a static reference to the application Context is technically safe). There are two ways to achieve that:

**1) Early initialization
2) Lazy initialization**

Read more on following link
https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/kotlin-singletons-with-argument-194ef06edd9e

Use this, it might help you

Comment: Link only answers aren't answers. Include the important part of that Medium article in your answer.